# $|A|\le |B| $implies$ |P(A)|\le|P(B)| $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> If cardinality of set $A$ is less or equal to the cardinality of set
>   $B$ then cardinality of the power set of $A$ is less or equal to the
>   cardinality of power set of $B$

This holds for finite sets, i want to know if it does for infinte ones too. I tried to do a proof:

Since $|A|\le |B|$ then there exist a  one to one function $f: A  \to B$

To show $ |P(A)|\le|P(B)|  $  we have to find a one to one function $g: P(A) \to P(B)$

Define $g$ such that it maps  $\{a_k\}~\to \{f(a_k)\}$

Likewise $\{a_j,~...~,~a_n\}~\to \{f(a_j),~...~,~f(a_n)\}$.

$g$ is injective because $f$ is. I am not sure  if $g$ is well defined for infinte subsets ?

Comment: Remove the subscripts and you should be better off.  Let $f$ be such an injective function from $A$ to $B$.  Let $g$ be the function such that a subset $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ maps to $\{f(x)~:~x\in X\}\in\mathcal{P}(B)$.  This way, we can talk about uncountable sets as well.  It remains to show that $g$ is in fact well defined here (*that the outputs are in fact actually elements of $\mathcal{P}(B)$*) and that it is in fact injective.

Comment: @JMoravitz do you think i should edit the question to implement your idea

Comment: No, but you can post it as an answer.